# ios gallery view .txt,tiff,.pdf ,png,jpeg,xls titanium appcelerator?

Tags: ios, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, image-gallery

I have to save .txt,.png,.jpeg,.pdf,.xls files to ios gallery .i need to slect that file when we open the gallery from titanium appceleraor.is it possile in titanium or is there any way to view and save this files in galllery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media-method-saveToPhotoGallery to save a photo to the gallery.

Comment: i want browse those extenion file from gallery to my application../

Comment: You mean you want to select an image form the device photo gallery? Then use http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media-method-openPhotoGallery

Comment: thanks for ur  reply i am able to open gallery  and browse png,jpeg files then i select any image i appended to my imageview  .But i need to select .pdf ,xls file from gallery to my application to set for imageview?

Comment: @VenkatAtluru you cannot select non-image files from the photo gallery. You mean to select from iCloud? That's currently not supported in Titanium Core and I haven't seen a module for it either.